# Не могу заблокировать переход с фрагмента в MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

У меня такая проблема:

в MainActivity загружается фрагмент HomeFragment.
[image: вот]

Вот, если нажать на кнопку назад, то меня возвращает в MainActivity и соответственно экран белый.
Попытался исправить - добавлял onBackPressed без super - итог, эта проблема исправилась, но у меня в приложении есть другие разделы (тоже фрагменты) и из них вернуться к HomeFragment стало невозможно. Как можно исправить?

Код загрузки фрагмента:

```
private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Остальные разделы приложения вызываются этим же кодом из HomeFragment.

Comment: Проверяй текущий фрагмент, и для опредленного не выполняй super метод.

Comment: `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` не делайте для первого фрагмента

Comment: Yura Ivanov, спасибо, мне помог ваш ответ